# C# Foreach on List is very slow

Tags: c#

I have a `foreach` that goes through `response`, `response` is a list that can take up to 230,000 records, `foreach response` it will filter and sum a second list called `_MaterialIssued`, this list contains max 30,000 records, in the following `if` it will only enter if `Issued` is bigger than 0 which will occur only about 15% of the time, next it will try to get the `itemOnhand` from the `_Onhand` list that contains max 17,000 records, in the following `if` it will go in about 85% of the time, when I wrote the code inside this block is where the performance dropped dramatically, in this `if` I will go back and filter `response` for all the child items and loop through them changing the `_onhand` list and the `response` list!

To go through this `foreach` depends on the machine I use but takes from 45 to 75 minutes and I cannot find what line is my bottleneck or how I can improve performance for this code block.

```cs
foreach (var b in response)
{
    var Issued = _MaterialIssued.Where(x => x.ItemId == b.ItemId && x.Job == b.Job).Sum(c => c.Qty);

    if (Issued > 0)
    {
        var prctIssued = Issued / b.QtyDemand;
        var childItems = response.Where(x => x.Job == b.Job && x.BomPath.StartsWith(b.BomPath));

        foreach (var child in childItems)
        {
            child.QtyIssued = child.QtyDemand * prctIssued;
        }
    }
    var itemOnhand = _OnHand.Where(x => x.ItemId == b.ItemId).FirstOrDefault();

    if (itemOnhand.Onhand > 0)
    {
        decimal prctOnhand = 1;
        var childItems = response.Where(x => x.Job == b.Job && x.BomPath.StartsWith(b.BomPath) && x.ItemId != b.ItemId && x.SiteRef == b.SiteRef && x.QtyIssued < x.QtyDemand);
        var DemandWithIssued = b.QtyDemand - b.QtyIssued;
        if (itemOnhand.Onhand < DemandWithIssued)
        {
            prctOnhand = itemOnhand.Onhand / DemandWithIssued;
        }

        itemOnhand.Onhand -= DemandWithIssued * prctOnhand;
        foreach (var child in childItems)
        {
            child.QtyParentAvailable = (child.QtyDemand - child.QtyIssued) * prctOnhand;
        }
    }
}
```

The model for `_OnHand` is

```cs
private class ItemOnhand
{
    public string ItemId { get; set; }
    public string SiteRef { get; set; }
    public decimal Onhand { get; set; }
}
```

The model for `_MaterialIssued` is

```cs
public class FiniteDemandBase
{
    public string ItemId { get; set; }
    public string Item { get; set; }
    public string JobId { get; set; }
    public string Job { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public string SiteRef { get; set; }
    public decimal Qty { get; set; }
}
```

The model for `response` is

```cs
public class FiniteDemand
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public string BomPath { get; set; }
    public string SiteRef { get; set; }
    public string Job { get; set; }
    public string ItemId { get; set; }
    public string JobId { get; set; }
    public string ParentItemId { get; set; }
    public decimal QtyPerUnit { get; set; }
    public decimal QtyDemand { get; set; }
    public decimal QtyOnhand { get; set; }
    public decimal QtyWip { get; set; }
    public decimal QtyOnhandRunning { get; set; }
    public decimal QtyInSchedule { get; set; }
    public decimal QtyIssued { get; set; }
    public decimal QtyParentAvailable { get; set; }
    public decimal QtyDemandNeeded { get; set; }
    public decimal QtyDemandNeededRunning { get; set; }
}
```

I tried changing the `_OnHand` list to a `HashSet` but the performance was the same.

Comment: What about actually measuring where time goes then look at the specific part more closely?

Comment: I have been trying to do that, I am using Visual Studio for MAC and cannot get performance by line working, apparently only available for windows

Comment: Setup a Project with BenchmarkDotnet. Select a golden sample of your input data, so you don't have to wait for hours, each time. Run the Benchmark. Copy the function and make improvements. Add it to the benchmark. Run your horses. Repeat.

Comment: I noticed that you have two queries that contain `response.Where(x => x.Job == b.Job && x.BomPath.StartsWith(b.BomPath));`. It might help if you just run this query once and save the results. Then you can add `savedResults.Where(x.ItemId != b.ItemId && x.SiteRef == b.SiteRef && x.QtyIssued < x.QtyDemand)` when you need to filter them further.

Comment: If this is going against a database, you might want to create an index on the `BomPath` column to improve performance of `StartsWith` queries.

Comment: Might also be worth using `JobId` instead of `Job`, and check if `JobId` and `ItemId` really are `strings`? Comparisons would probably be faster if they were `ints` or `guids`

Answer (score 2):

Let's break down your code into parts which contain an explicit of implicit iteration:

Iteration over `response` — `n`-times:

```
foreach (var b in response)
{
```

Nested iteration over `_MaterialIssued` — `m`-times:

```
    var Issued = _MaterialIssued.Where(x => x.ItemId == b.ItemId && x.Job == b.Job).Sum(c => c.Qty);
```

Nested iteration over `response` (*again*) — `n`-times:

```
        var childItems = response.Where(x => x.Job == b.Job && x.BomPath.StartsWith(b.BomPath));
```

Nested iteration over `_OnHand` — up to `h`-times:

```
    var itemOnhand = _OnHand.Where(x => x.ItemId == b.ItemId).FirstOrDefault();
```

Nested iteration over `response` (**again**) — `n`-times:

```
        var childItems = response.Where(x => x.Job == b.Job && x.BomPath.StartsWith(b.BomPath) && x.ItemId != b.ItemId && x.SiteRef == b.SiteRef && x.QtyIssued < x.QtyDemand);
```

Hence, the complexity of your algorithm is: `O(n * (m + n + h + n)) = O(2*n^2 + n*(m+h))`!

If the number of responses is 230,000, we are speaking about 52.9 *billion* iterations! No wonder it runs for ages :)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds an awful lot like you're trying to manage a database. I would suggest you go all the way and do exactly that, and look into using something like `MySQL` instead.

E.g.:

[Create a database and add tables in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/create-a-sql-database-by-using-a-designer?view=vs-2022)

[Create a SQL Server Database programmatically by using ADO.NET and Visual C# .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/visualstudio/csharp/language-compilers/create-sql-server-database-programmatically)

Whilst, technically, a `List` can contain up to two billion elements, once you're above a few thousand you'll start to run into trouble. They aren't really meant for the sort of heavy data processing you're attempting. *That* is exactly what database engines are for.

Comment: I am using a database, but I need all the rows to perform some calculations with the data I have in my database plus some data I get from external sources.

Comment: It should be possible to perform the calculations _in_ the database. The fact that you aren't doing that is what led me to assume you weren't using a database. If you're labouriously copying large amounts of data out of a database into objects that aren't designed to handle it, then there's something wrong with your essential approach to processing the data.

Comment: ^^ this. `_MaterialIssued.Where(x => x.ItemId == b.ItemId && x.Job == b.Job).Sum(c => c.Qty);` - this alone with a Database's Indexing capabilities and caching ... versus whatever Linq makes of this. Not to speak of the other queries.